# Problem with course files not matching my local files

Tags: android

I have been trying to follow a couple of introductory courses for android development (a pluralsight course, and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCSlZIUj18Y&ab_channel=AnushkaMadusanka) youtube course) but in each case I have found that the template project that I get in my local copy of android studio differs significantly from those that are used in the course.

As an example, the youtube course refers to an `activity_main.xml` file which does not exist in my local project files. For the pluralsight course, it was that the content of the files did not match, so I had spend a lot of time trying to work out how to achieve the intent of the course (assign an action to a button etc) to the newer layout which took a huge amount of time and stifled my learning.

How can I make sure that the files in the project template exactly match those that the instructor uses? Some ideas I had:

- Download the (old) version of android studio which matches what the instructor is using? It seems like a bad idea to deliberately download an older version of android studio.
- Find a course that has git commits at regular checkpoints? This seems like a workaround, and is also pretty uncommon apparently (I looked at a few and only found the completed code for the course, no step-by-step commits).

Comment: Do you mean the template project generated by Android Studio when you go to new project and tell it to create a project?  Yes, those change constantly. Pretty much every release, they update it to use new features.  Development moves fast, don't expect this kind of thing to remain static.  I would not suggest downgrading to an older Android Studio, because when you move to the next example that's newer it will be totally different again.  I would just type the files as they have them into Android Studio.

Comment: But basically, any course that's more than a month or two old is likely going to have a different template.  The purpose of the template isn't a learner's tool for a particular course, it's to set up a minimal project for someone who wants to use the latest techniques.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, the "template project generated by Android Studio..." as you say. So if we take my example involving `activity_main.xml`, I cannot find a file with this name nor can I find the contents of the file (keywords etc that I see on screen in the course video) in any other place in the project. As a beginner, what am I supposed to do? Just typing what I see in the video into a new file will not make the project use the file.

Comment: The project uses that file when you call setContenView(R.layout.activity_main) in the activity.  That tells it to find an xml resource file named activity_main.xml and inflate it into the screen.  But yes, you'd need to copy a few files that way-  likely the manifest, the activity, an xml layout file, and possibly an xml strings file

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but my question is more "how is a beginner supposed to know this?" It seems like a huge flaw in the concept of a video tutorial if the template that the tutorial is based on is not a constant.

Comment: Unfortunately your timing sucks for using this template at the moment-  Google is now pushing their big idea of Jetpack Compose, an entirely different way of doing UIs from the Views idea that has been around since v1.  So they've migrated a lot of the templates to it.  If your version of Android Studio has the option, look for a template that says "Empty Views Activity" or the like

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks! Actually I saw these and avoided them since the tutorial said just "Empty Activity" etc. Will give them a go.

Comment: @GabeSechan Put your advice in an answer and I will accept it